# Insert br tag between uploaded images in summernote

Tags: javascript, file-upload, summernote

Can't deal with summernote editor.
When I am uploading an images into summernote editor, I want to insert 
 tag after each uploaded image, for example:
I want to get

```
<p>
Text....
<img src="img1.png">
<br>
<img src="img2.png">
<br>
Text....
</p>
```

But have:

```
<p>
<img src="img1.png">
<img src="img2.png">
<br>
</p>
```

Here is the code which insert images after upload into editor:

```
for (var i in url.uploaded_files) {
   $(selector).summernote("insertImage", url.path + url.uploaded_files[i]);
   $(selector).summernote("insertHTML", '<br>');
}
```

Also:

```
$(selector).summernote("insertNode", document.createElement("BR"));
```

doesn't work.

Please advice how to insert br or any tag after uploaded images

Comment: Does this work?   var html = $('<br>'); //get the html
    var editable=$('.note-editable');
    YourSelector.insertNode(editable, html);

Answer (score 1):

Problem fixed with CSS. Simply added display:block; for all images inside of .note-editable node.